# How do I programmatically update values during row editing in igx-grid?

Tags: angular, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I am using Angular 11 and current [Ignite UI Agnular](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular).

I have a [grid](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/grid) which has columns users can edit (name, active, type, etc.) and other columns which they cannot (parameters changed in other screens, audit columns, etc.):

```html
<igx-grid #grid [data]="data" width="100%" height="500px" [primaryKey]="'ProductID'" [rowEditable]="true">
    <igx-column field="ProductName" header="ProductName" [dataType]="'string'"></igx-column>
    <igx-column field="UpdatedBy" [dataType]="'string'" [editable]="false"></igx-column>
    <igx-column field="UpdatedDate" [dataType]="'date'" [editable]="false"></igx-column>
  </igx-grid>
```

I want to know how to programmatically modify the "UpdatedBy" and "UpdatedDate" columns when row editing is finished?

Answer (score 1):

The [`rowEditDone`](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxgridcomponent.html#roweditdone) event of the [`IgxGridComponent`](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxgridcomponent.html) can be handled to manually change the targeted properties' values of the current row object:

```js
public rowEditDoneHandler(args: IGridEditDoneEventArgs) {
      const currRowIndex = this.data.indexOf(args.rowData);
      this.data[currRowIndex].UpdatedBy = this.username || 'Anonymous';
      this.data[currRowIndex].UpdatedDate = new Date();
      this.data = [...this.data];
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/igx-grid-programmatically-update-values-so?file=src/app/grid/grid-add-row-sample/grid-add-row-sample.component.ts) is also a StackBlitz sample demonstrating this approach.